# How do I truncate the Django log in DEBUG whenever I run the development server?

Tags: django, logging

I want my Django `logging` output file to be (re)created on each execution of the server, rather than appending to the previous run.

I am currently configuring my Django logging system via the `LOGGING` configuration dictionary, so I don't see how to just call `logging.handlers.FileHandler` with different arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is bad practice to automagically delete logs. If you still want to go ahead: Execute code on startup with `AppConfig.ready()`.

### Example

Executing any code on start up if you're in debug mode:

```
# rock_n_roll/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class RockNRollConfig(AppConfig):

    def ready(self):
         if setting.DEBUG:
             # Delete, rename or do whatever to your log files.
```

You can make your application load this AppConfig subclass by default as follows:

```
# rock_n_roll/__init__.py

default_app_config = 'rock_n_roll.apps.RockNRollConfig'
```

Read the documentation especially the warning and notes. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready

Note: Don't be surprised if fiddling your logs bites you.

Comment: I don't want to clear the logs on the production servers, only for local development.

Comment: Still it's worth pointing out that it is not that good of idea. People might use this and think its okay because SO says so ;). The app config ready is what you need. Wrap the deleting stuff in a condition `if settings.DEBUG == True`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just delete or move the file before running the server?

Comment: Sure, though I was hoping for a simple and non-hacky way to do it within the logging system itself.